# Why do CORS policies block my ip from my API?

Tags: node.js, express, cors, angular5

when I make a request to my api in production I get this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://...:300/api/ext/companies/sort=%22code%22:-1&limit=1' from origin
'http://...:90' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

How do I solve this problem?

my frontend is developed in angular 5.

my api is developed in nodejs and this is my configuration

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization, Database');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

  next();
});
```

Comment: This is because in some situations (not all) browsers will refuse to accept Access-Control-Allow-Origin value of *. The correct implementation of CORS on the server is check the origin and referer fields, if exist put the value back in Access-Control-Allow-Origin (this is where you can check if the requesting website is actually allowed to talk to you). Ncmettin's answer gives you a nice plugin that will automatically do this for you in express but this is the reason why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Instead of:

```
const express = require("express");
```

Try this:

```
const express = require("express").use("*", cors());
```

And remove it:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization, Database');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

  next();
});
```